# Magento 2 custom options title not working while csv import

Tags: magento2, import, custom-options

I am trying to import product through CSV file in magento 2.getting some errors while importing.

custom options (custom_title with comma separated not working).

example: name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3**sku,option_title=Platinum(aaa,bbb,cccc)**

Can anybody help on this.